# Fetch Recent Media from user's device using Flutter's Photo Manager

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to fetch just 10 of the user's recent photos.

Below is the code I attempted using the flutter's photo_manager package that I felt could help me achieve that but it never returns even though I've been granted permissions.

```
Future<List<AssetEntity>> _fetchRecentAssetsWithGrantedPermissions() async {
    print("Loading assets now"); //This gets called
    final List<AssetEntity> entities = await PhotoManager.getAssetListPaged(
      page: 0,
      pageCount: 10,
      filterOption: FilterOptionGroup(
        orders: [
          const OrderOption(
            type: OrderOptionType.createDate,
            asc: false,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
    print("Assets Loaded"); //This never gets called
    print(entities);
    return entities;
  }
```

Where could I be going wrong?